# Unable to delete daemonSet in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I've created a daemonSet in k8s under the namespace kube-system.
While trying to delete the deamonSet it got stuck (also when I force it)

I've already tried to set a **updateStrategy: RollingUpdate** To the Yaml and *kubectl apply* reports that: **daemonset.extensions "fluentd-logzio" configured**

**Edited:**

non RBAC daemonset:

https://app.logz.io/#/dashboard/data-sources/Kubernetes

Thx.

Comment: please, could you tell us how did you installed fluentd?

Comment: Edited:

non RBAC daemonset:

https://app.logz.io/#/dashboard/data-sources/Kubernetes

Comment: which command did you use for creation and delete?

Comment: **Creation:** kubectl create -n kube-system -f daemonset.yaml     |
**Delete:** kubectl delete ds -n kube-system fluentd-logzio     |
**Apply:** kubectl apply -f daemonset.yaml -n kube-system

Comment: what the error in the: `kubectl describe ds fluentd-logzio -n kube-system`?

Answer (score 1):

I realised that one of my nodes were **'not ready'** because one of the K8s services was crushed so first I had to reload the crushed service and then my node back to ready state so later I got the possibility to delete the daemonSet.